# ¿Como puedo desarrollar un banner de estado en lado servidorpara un script que se ejecuta en lado cliente?

Tags: javascript, php, html5, script, javascript-metodo

Alguien sabe como puedo desarrollar un banner de estado en JavaScript  para saber si se está interactuando con el banner y que se vea  desde el lado servidor , que se pueda desplegar desde cualquier CMS o framework

Comment: ¿como se interactua con un banner?  ¿te refieres a si se muestra o no?  Si el banner lo alojas tu entonces verás las peticiones en el log de tu servidor web. Lo de cualquier CMS o framework es simple supongo, dándoles el código para que lo pongan que tampoco tiene porque ser complicado, supongo que con un `<img src="https://midominio.com/mibanner.jpg">` ya les vale (en el modo más simple posible) y luego, analizando tu log de tu servidor web, puedes contar las veces que se ha mostrado y desde donde mediante el referrer (si tu log lo guarda, esperemos que si).

Comment: Aparte de lo que te comenta masterguru, ¿a que te refieres con un "banner de estado"? ¿a que te refieres con "saber si se está interactuando con el banner? ¿que interaccion pretendes tener en el banner? por favor aclara tu pregunta.